# Provide concrete type for Generic Protocol implementation

Tags: swift, oop, swift2, swift-protocols

Is it possible to do following:

```
protocol A: class {
    typealias T: AnyObject
}
extension A {
    func testA(a:Self, _ t:T)->Void{
        print(a, t)
    }
}
class B:A {
    typealias T = String
}
```

In other words I have protocol and want to provide concrete type just in the class which conforms it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be fine. The only issue with the code you have there is that `String` is not an `AnyObject`.

You just need:

```
protocol A: class {
    typealias T
}
extension A {
    func testA(a:Self, _ t:T)->Void{
        print(a, t)
    }
}
class B:A {
    typealias T = String
}
```